# exponential generating function - Fibonacci recurrence relation

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions, fibonacci-numbers

I am learning about exponential generating functions from some free tutorials and I recently learned how to use ordinary generating functions to solve the Fibonacci recurrence. I was wondering how can one solve the Fibonacci recurrence using exponential generating functions. I have not seen many examples of recurrences being solved using exponential generating functions so this will be very helpful to me.

Thank you.

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1133712/what-is-the-need-of-exponential-generating-functions-on-combinatorial-problems?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: See Example 1 in Section 2.3 of generatingfunctionology: https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfology2.pdf

Comment: I have not studied differential equations before so there is part in the example that I am not following. So the author just solves the diff eq and says to apply the operator $[x^n/n!]$. Is there an example w/o diferentialf equations @awkward

Comment: As far as I know, solving the Fibonacci recurrence with an exponential generating function inevitably involves a differential equation.

Answer (score 2):

$F_n=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left[\phi^n+\left(1-\phi\right)^n\right]$, where $\phi=\dfrac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$ (golden ratio)

$\quad\sum_{n\ge0} F_n\dfrac{z^n}{n!} \\ =\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\sum_{n\ge0} \left[\phi^n+\left(1-\phi\right)^n\right]\dfrac{z^n}{n!}\\=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\sum_{n\ge0}\left[\dfrac{\left(\phi z\right)^n}{n!}+\dfrac{\left(z-\phi z\right)^n}{n!}\right]\\=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left[e^{z\phi}+e^{z\left(1-\phi\right)}\right] $

Answer (score 0):

Your recurrence is $F_{n + 2} = F_{n + 1} + F_n$ and $F_0 = 0, F_1 = 1$. Start by defining $f(z) = \sum_{n \ge 1} F_n \frac{z^n}{n!}$, multiply your recurrence by $z^n/n!$ and sum over $n \ge 0$, recognize some sums:

$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n \ge 0} F_{n + 2} \frac{z^n}{n!}
  &= \sum_{n \ge 0} F_{n + 1} \frac{z^n}{n!} + \sum_{n \ge 0} F_n \frac{z^n}{n!} \\
\frac{d^2}{d z^2} f(z)
  &= \frac{d}{d z} f(z) + f(z)
\end{align*}$

You get a differential equation, from the initial values you get that $f(0) = 0$, $f'(0) = 1$.