# Why use the exponential in moment-generating function?

Tags: statistics, exponential-function, moment-generating-functions

When trying to understand the moment-generating function, I've stumbled upon this general function:

Mx(t) = E[e^tx], t ∈ R

I understand that you have X = (X1, ... Xn) a series of random variables and that you draw a vector through tX.

It may sounds naive, but why use the exponential of that series? Why not ln for instance? After all, both are monotonous, continuous, positive on R? (and are also closely connected, though ln is much slower than e).

Thank you very much for your insights!

Jordane

Comment: For any sequence $a_0, a_1, a_2, \ldots$, the (ordinary) generating function is $g(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \cdots = \sum_n a_n x^n$. The idea is that this single function contains the complete information about the whole sequence, since the coefficient of $x^n$ is exactly the $n$-th term of the sequence. However, given a generating function in closed form, it's not always easy to find this coefficient for a general $n$.

Comment: On the other hand, we can also define the _exponential_ generating function of the sequence as $f(x) = \sum_n a_n \frac{x^n}{n!}$. Again, the $n$-th term is exactly the coefficient of $\frac{x^n}{n!}$ in this series. If we know the function in closed form, then one way to obtain this coefficient is to differentiate the function $n$ times and set $x = 0$. That is, $a_n = f^{(n)}(0)$ [you can verify this easily; or else recall the form of Maclaurin's series].

Comment: $$M_X(t)  = \mathbb E[e^{tX}] = \mathbb E\left[\sum_n \frac{t^n}{n!} X^n\right] = \sum_n \mathbb E[X^n] \frac{x^n}{n!}$$ is the exponential generating function of the series of $n$-th (raw) moments $\mathbb E[X^n]$ of the random variable $X$.

Comment: Thank you so much M. Vinay this makes total sense now!

Comment: Glad to help. But I see I've made a stupid typo there. It should be $$M_X(t) = \sum_n \mathbb E[X^n] \dfrac{t^n}{n!}$$ (not $x^n$).

Comment: @M.Vinay superficially, it seems the approach of differentiating $n$ times and then setting $x = 0$ should work for both the ordinary and the exponential generating functions. If this is correct, what's the motivation for using the exponential series? What am I missing? PS - sorry for the necro...

Comment: @ahron Here are some general reasons for why the egf is used sometimes: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1133748/152030. I'll give a more specific reason for this case: The mgf has the nice property that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables and $Z = X + Y$, then $M_Z(t) = M_X(t) M_Y(t)$ (obvious when you consider $\mathbb E[e^{t(X + Y)}]$ [and note that $e^{tX}$ and $e^{tY}$ will also be indepedendent]). More generally, if $Z = aX + bY$, then $M_Z(t) = M_X(at) M_Y(bt)$. If you used an ogf, you'd have $\mathbb E[(1 - tX)^{-1}]$, and that wouldn't work out so nicely (or at all).

Comment: Understood. Thank you so much!